# networkx and iteration of lists - piece of code I cannot understand

Tags: python, list, networkx

I'm new to the python language and have been working with the `networkx` package. Basically I have a list of customers and producers and want a function that retrieves the list of the current list based on these types.

**Here is the relevant code for the function that retrieves customers:**

```
def customers_iter(self, data=False):

    """ Return an iterator over all customers.

        If the network is changed during iteration, the iterator becomes
        invalid.

        Parameters
        -----------

        data -  if True, return a list of (name, attributes) pairs, such
                that attributes == net.node[name]. Otherwise,
                only a list of customer names is returned. Default is
                False.
    """

    if data:
        return (n for n in self.nodes_iter(data=True) 
                    if self.node[n[0]]["type"] == "customer")
    else:
        return (n for n in self.nodes_iter() 
                    if self.node[n]["type"] == "customer")
```

My question is specifically regarding the if- and else statement. What is the point if first checking the first node n[0]? Doesn't the statement in the else-section define exactly the same thing?

Regards,
jazy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the doc comment:

```
data -  if True, return a list of (name, attributes) pairs, such
        that attributes == net.node[name]. Otherwise,
        only a list of customer names is returned. Default is
        False.
```

Assuming, that `data` parameter has the same meaning in the `self.node_iter` function, the first branch (`if`) should filter pairs of `(name, attributes)`, however the second one (`else`) should filter only `name`s.

Assuming, also, that `self.node` is a dictionary-like structure for holding associative pairs `name` -> `node`, it is easy to see, that in the first branch we have to retrieve the `name` from the `tuple` (which is `n[0]`), while in the second branch we could just use `n` as the node name.

Comment: Thank you so much! I understand it now :)

Comment: You are always welcome! Fell free to mark the answer as accepted in order to help people facing the same problem.